# How to select all text in table cells in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Trying to write a simple script to give me all the cell contents of a table.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'http://127.0.0.1/html5css3'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td//text()")

for t in table:
    print t
```

I have yet to find a tutorial on xpath syntax that covers from the basics to the advanced.

**Sample input:**

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Vehicle</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Rating</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Duration</td>
    <td>Latex</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Super Paint</td>
    <td>Latex</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A-100</td>
    <td>Latex</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Macropoxy</td>
    <td>Epoxy</td>
    <td>62</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My eventual goal is to do something like  PRINT td[2] Where td[4] is greater than 3

Comment: Can you show us content of variable table? What type is it?

Comment: Are you hoping that `type(table[0]) == WebElement` or `type(table[0])==str`?

Comment: The example you give can be handled more easily with [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`xml.etree.elementtree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Unless you are confident that you require the browser automation features of selenium, you might be better off using these interfaces instead.

Answer (score 3):

When I run your program I get this error message:

> > The result of the xpath expression "//td//text()" is: [object XrayWrapper [object Text]]. It should be an element.

Sure enough, when I run that expression in `lxml`, I get a list of strings.

Apparently, `.find_elements*` only want to return WebElements; they don't want to return strings.

Depending upon your greater requirements, try one of these:

```
list_of_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td') # return elements
list_of_text = [t.text for t in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td')] # return strings
```

Although, if it were me, I'd want to have some structure in my result:

```
list_of_lists = [[td.text
                  for td in tr.find_elements_by_xpath('td')]
                  for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')]
list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(list_of_lists[0],row)) for row in list_of_lists[1:]]
```

With that, your goal is easily within reach:

> > My eventual goal is to do something like PRINT td[2] Where td[4] is greater than 3

```
print [row['Vehicle'] for row in list_of_dicts if int(row['Rating']) > 3]
```

Here is a final program that might do what you want:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = 'file:///tmp/x.html'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

list_of_lists = [[td.text
                  for td in tr.find_elements_by_xpath('td')]
                  for tr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr')]
list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(list_of_lists[0],row)) for row in list_of_lists[1:]]

for t in list_of_dicts:
    if int(t['Rating']) > 3:
        print t['Vehicle']
```